# adding bounce effect to appearance of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-animation

How can I add a bounce effect when I am about to show an UIImageView as a subview? Do I have to use CoreAnimation to do this? My only guess right now is to use CAKeyframeAnimation, please let me know if there's a better way. Here's my current code:

```
 CABasicAnimation * theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    theAnimation.delegate = self;
    theAnimation.duration = 1.0;
    theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:notif.center.y];
    theAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:notif.center.y-20];
    theAnimation.repeatCount = 3;
```

Comment: Hi Adit. Could you please elaborate? What exactly do you mean by a "bounce effect"? Do you have any example to show?

Comment: What I mean is that when it shows I want it to bounce up and down a bit for couple times. something like http://www.entheosweb.com/Flash/bouncing_effect.asp

Answer (score 32, accepted):

y-axis animation using CABasicAnimation:

```
CGPoint origin = self.imageView.center;
CGPoint target = CGPointMake(self.imageView.center.x, self.imageView.center.y+100);
CABasicAnimation *bounce = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
bounce.duration = 0.5;
bounce.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin.y];
bounce.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target.y];
bounce.repeatCount = 2;
bounce.autoreverses = YES;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:bounce forKey:@"position"];
```

If you want to implement shrink and grow you have to add a CGAffineTransformMakeScale, eg:

```
// grow
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
imageView.transform = transform;
```

Comment: where are you actually setting imageView to the UIView animation? can't you use CABasicAnimation?

Comment: Your bounce animation doesn't work. Because the view would end up in the new position, not coming back to old position.. That's not a bounce at all..

Comment: @Philip007 the CABasicAnimation makes the image go down, then up to its original position, as in the Flash example posted as a comment above.

Comment: Works great!! :) Make sure you add QuatzCore framework in your project. Thanks.

Comment: Nice and easy solution

Answer (score 8):

Bouncy (expand/shrink) animation in **Swift**:

```
var selected: Bool {
  willSet(selected) {
    let expandTransform:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
    if (!self.selected && selected) {
      self.imageView.image = SNStockCellSelectionAccessoryViewImage(selected)
      self.imageView.transform = expandTransform
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4,
        delay:0.0,
        usingSpringWithDamping:0.40,
        initialSpringVelocity:0.2,
        options: .CurveEaseOut,
        animations: {
          self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(expandTransform)
        }, completion: {
          //Code to run after animating
          (value: Bool) in
      })

    }
  }
}

var imageView:UIImageView
```

If `imageView` is correctly added to the view as a subview, toggling between `selected = false` to `selected = true` should swap the image with a bouncy animation. `SNStockCellSelectionAccessoryViewImage` just returns a different image based on the current selection state, see below:

```
private let SNStockCellSelectionAccessoryViewPlusIconSelected:UIImage = UIImage(named:"PlusIconSelected")!
private let SNStockCellSelectionAccessoryViewPlusIcon:UIImage = UIImage(named:"PlusIcon")!

private func SNStockCellSelectionAccessoryViewImage(selected:Bool) -> UIImage {
  return selected ? SNStockCellSelectionAccessoryViewPlusIconSelected : SNStockCellSelectionAccessoryViewPlusIcon
}
```

The GIF example below is a bit slowed down, the actual animation happens faster:

[image: UIImageView bounce animation Gif]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                      delay:0
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
      initialSpringVelocity:0.5
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|
                             UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat)
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = view.frame;
                     frame.origin.y -= 8;
                     view.frame = frame;
                 } completion:nil];
```

Play with the values to get different effects.

Answer (score 1):

@Jano's answer in Swift

```
let origin:CGPoint = self.image.center
let target:CGPoint = CGPointMake(self.image.center.x, self.image.center.y+100)
let bounce = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
bounce.duration = 1
bounce.fromValue = origin.y
bounce.toValue = target.y
bounce.repeatCount = 2
bounce.autoreverses = true
self.image.layer.addAnimation(bounce, forKey: "position")
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed this [link](https://evgenii.com/blog/spring-button-animation-with-swift/)

```
func imageViewBounceEffect() {

    yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.35, delay: 0,
                               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.25,
                               initialSpringVelocity: 5,
                               options: .curveEaseOut,
                               animations: {
                                
        self.yourImageView.transform = .identity
    })
}
```