# Jumping effect on uibuttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uianimation

Here in my app i used the moving sub View.If it reach y=150,i want to make a buttons in jumping effect,i tried this link [adding bounce effect to appearance of UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787494/adding-bounce-effect-to-appearance-of-uiimageview) it working in horizontal direction ,i want a vertical direction,Here my code,

```
-(void)godown 
 {
if (movingview.center.y < 150) movingview.center = CGPointMake(movingview.center.x, movingview.center.y +5);
if(movingview.center.y ==150)
{
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"bounce" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
  [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];  
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3,1.3);
  bt1.transform = transform;
  bt2.transform=transform;
 [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
}
```

Please help me to change into jumping effect(vertically)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this. You can make some changes so it suits your need,

```
        CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
        anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        anim.duration = 0.125;
        anim.repeatCount = 1;
        anim.autoreverses = YES;
        anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
        anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 1.0)];
        [senderView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

Here i found a useful post on this attractive pop animation. Hope it is what you want

[image]

```
@IBAction func btnCancel_click(_ sender: Any)
{
    btnCancel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.50, y: 0.50)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                   delay: 0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
                   options: .allowUserInteraction,
                   animations: { [weak self] in
                    self?.btnCancel.transform = .identity
        },
                   completion: nil)
}
```

source: http://evgenii.com/blog/spring-button-animation-with-swift/

Answer (score 4):

Try this code..

```
- (IBAction)bounce {
    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];///use transform
    theAnimation.duration=0.4;  
    theAnimation.repeatCount=2;
    theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;  
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]; 
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-20];
    [yourButton.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateTranslation"];//animationkey    
}
```

see the whole answer from [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/discussion/comment/295325) link

Answer (score 0):

And the swift version

```
    func jumpButtonAnimation(sender: UIButton) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        animation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.3)
        animation.duration = 0.1
        animation.repeatCount = 0
        animation.autoreverses = true
        sender.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1 ,
                               animations: {
                                self.buttonName.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        },
                                completion: { finish in
                                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1){
                                self.buttonName.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                                }
    })
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer? Posting just a code snippet is not a good way. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)